# BIOS Update within Linux

Tags: linux, bios

I want to enable PXE boot of current system's BIOS from Linux.

If modifying the BIOS content is not possible then is there any way to take the back up of current BIOS setting and dump it on identical other machine ? So that changes made on first machine's BIOS settings will be effective on Second identical machine's BIOS Settings

EDIT:

I came across an utility [flashrom](http://flashrom.org/Flashrom), which is allowing me dump the previously recorded file. But is there any way to modify only single option of BIOS (without dumping)

Comment: Why would modifying the BIOS content not be possible? If the machines are identical, they both would have a BIOS that allow switching on PXE. Or is this about not being able to access the 2nd machine to modify the BIOS settings?

Comment: What type of hardware is this? Is it a branded server? If so, there are some options...

Comment: Yes. It is branded and most of them are of prior 2000

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to change a BIOS setting of a machine you don't have KVM access to.

If they were 100% identical, it *could* work, but that would mean that all installed options and connected peripherals are the same and - important - that all those also have the same firmware versions.

So while technically feasible, I would not recommend to "copy" a BIOS to a remote machine, as you're likely to get into all kinds of troubles, ranging from a non-booting remote server to funny behavior of some of its components.